# How should Roslyn Analyzer actions handle async code?

Tags: c#, async-await, roslyn

I have a Roslyn analyzer which I've recently updated to use version 2.3 of CSharp.Workspaces. I found that when I build I get a warning like the following:

> Analyzer attempted to register an 'async' action, which is not supported.

Some of the actions I'm adding are async because they are calling async methods from the Roslyn API, like in the following hypothetical example.

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeProperty, SymbolKind.Property);
}

private async void AnalyzeProperty(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    var property = (IPropertySymbol) context.Symbol;
    foreach (var syntaxRef in property.DeclaringSyntaxReferences)
    {
        DoSomethingWith(await syntaxRef.GetSyntaxAsync());
    }
}
```

Should I just change any uses of `await` to `.Result` or `.Wait()` on the Task, or is there some other way I should correct my code in response to the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you shouldn't use await in synchronous context. that will cause timing issue that is hard to debug.

use synchronous version of the API.
http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxReference.cs,29

by the way, using async API with Wait() or Result might not as bad as using await in synchronous context, but it could be still bad since that might cause thread starvation since you are blocking current thread just to wait another thread to finish work and return.

best way is using synchronous API in synchronous context. and async API in asynchronous context.

Comment: Does this mean I should also write any helper methods for analyzer actions using sync APIs, and not write them async only calling .Result or Wait() at the end?

Comment: @RikkiGibson as an analyzer you are being run on a threadpool thread and no UI operations are waiting on you so it is safe to just do `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.  There is no need to write helper methods.